# Bad request with phpmyadmin on nginx with ssl (no clr)

Tags: nginx, ssl, phpmyadmin

I have a simple nginx configuration playing as a proxy to handle ssl requests.
The problem is when I log on phpmyadmin on `https://files.mysite.com/phpmyadmin`, it redirects me on `http://files.mysite.com:443` and throw a :
`400 Bad request: The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`
I've looked around here and on super user and can't find anything that would fit this problem
Here's the nginx configuration file :

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name files.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://files.mysite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
    server_name files.mysite.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/files.mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/files.mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    root /home/mysite/mysite.com/files;
    index index.html;

    location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php;
        include conf-available/php5.conf;
    }
}
```

I am using almost the same configuration on all subdomains with various web tools and no problem, so I am really confused !

Thanks for helping !

<s>EDIT: I've been asked to show the output of `wget -S files.mysite.com` so [here it is](https://pastebin.com/P86642Yg)

And, apprently, it is well redirected from http:80 to https:443 but then switchs back to http:443 for some reason</s>

EDIT2: Actually it's not redirecting to http:443 when `wget -S`, this is only achievied when I successfully log into phpmyadmin

Comment: what's the output of wget -S  https://files.mysite.com/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: [here is the output](https://pastebin.com/P86642Yg)

Comment: Are there any ".htaccess" files that would be responsible for the 2nd redirect?

Comment: If so, I can't find any, no

Comment: And no hints in the logs?

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing in the error log, all I've got is [access.log](https://pastebin.com/mKcwZt7y)